# Is it possible to draw a vertical line in the middle of the list view in android?

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to draw a vertical line in the middle of the list view in android.
I mean, can i able to split the list view.

If i do so, can i able to show the data in list-view on both sides.
I mean i would like to split the listview into two columns.

why im asking this because,here im creating one customised listview.. i would like to show that list view in to grid view format..But in grid view we cannot able to customize it right?

Suggestion please

Thanks for your precious time!...

Comment: i think using fragments will meet your requirement

Comment: It'd be way easy for you to use a GridView. You can set/choose number of columns on runtime.

Comment: am not sure... just try.... In listview text xml put this view  <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#000000" />

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper your xml code can draw a line,but can i able to show the data side by side?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not easy to understand..

Do you want 2 separate ListView side by side with a different scrolling or just to display 2 columns?

If you want to display 2 columns, a GridView seems to be your friend.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: i would like to split the listview into two columns

Comment: why im asking this because,here im creating one customised listview.. i would like to show that list view in to grid view format..But in grid view we cannot able to customize it right?

Comment: GridView is EXACTLY the same as a ListView. What you can do on List is faiseable on Grid